# Why do components in react need to be capitalized?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, when you declare a component in react with a lowercase first letter, it doesn't show up, without throwing an error. When you capitalise the component name, it does work.

What is it implemented like this? To avoid collision with existing html elements, or is this a bug?

```
var test = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Test</div>
    );
  }
});

var Screen = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <test/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

When I change `test` to `Test`, it works:

```
var Test = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Test</div>
    );
  }
});

var Screen = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Test/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [some react release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html)

> the JSX tag name convention (lowercase names refer to built-in components, capitalized names refer to custom components).

Comment: I would think that it would be possible to break the convention. If breaking the convention breaks the code, it's more than a convention.

Comment: Probably because it follows other OOP class naming conventions like Java

Answer (score -2):

React is actually just case sensitive.

There's a relevant github issue here where someone asks the same question. https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/76

Comment: The DOM is case insensitive (in HTML mode).

Comment: That github issue is talking about properties of DOM nodes, not element names.