# Unable to render custom component using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build an image slider using reactJS.
( [github link](https://github.com/sree-bh/snaPViewReact) )

I have created a react component 'snapviewer' to load the template in the view. On loading the page in the browser, I can see a blank tag being created as:

```
<snapviewer data-reactid=".0"></snapviewer>
```

There is no console error.

Note: I am absolutely new to ReactJS.

Code:

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react'),
    ReactDOM = require('react-dom'),
    lastSnap,
    ssInterval;

var basePath = 'resources/gallery/',
    snapList = [
        {
         path: basePath + 'Koala.jpg',
         cls: 'shown',
        },
        {
         path: basePath + 'Chrysanthemum.jpg',
         cls: 'next',
        },
     {
         path: basePath + 'Desert.jpg',
         cls: '',
        },
     {
         path: basePath + 'Penguins.jpg',
         cls: '',
        },
     {
         path: basePath + 'Tulips.jpg',
         cls: '',
        },
     {
         path: basePath + 'Lighthouse.jpg',
         cls: 'left'
        }
    ];

var newSlide = React.createClass({
   render: function() {

       return <div className={'slide-container ' + this.props.data.cls}>
      <div style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.props.data.path + ')'}}
     className="slide"></div>
     </div>;
   }
});

var snapViewer = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function () {
  lastSnap = this.props.snData.length - 1;

  return {
   action: 'Play',
   animationProgress: false,
   currentIdx: 0,
   nextIdx: 1,
   prevIdx: lastSnap
  };
    },
    prev: function (event) {
     this.fnslideShow(true, true);
 },
 slideShow: function (event) {
  if (this.pause()) {
   return;
  }
  
  this.setState({action: 'Pause'});
  ssInterval = setInterval(this.fnslideShow, 5000);
 },
 next: function (event) {
  this.fnslideShow(true);
 },
 pause: function () {
  if (!!ssInterval) {
   clearInterval(ssInterval);
   ssInterval = null;
   this.setState({action: 'Play'});
   
   return true;
  }
 },
 fnslideShow: function (stopSS, isPrev) {
  
  if (stopSS) {
   this.pause();
  }
  
  if (this.state.animationProgress) {
   return;
  }
  
  this.setState({animationProgress: true});
  
  if (isPrev) {
   setTimeout(function () {
    this.props.snData[this.state.prevIdx].cls = 'animate shown';
    this.props.snData[this.state.currentIdx].cls = 'next';
    this.props.snData[this.state.nextIdx].cls = '';
    this.setState({nextIdx: this.state.currentIdx});
    this.setState({currentIdx: this.state.prevIdx});
    this.setState({prevIdx: (this.state.currentIdx === 0 ?
      lastSnap: this.state.prevIdx - 1)});
   }.bind(this), 1);
  } else {
   setTimeout(function () {
    this.props.snData[this.state.prevIdx].cls = '';
    this.props.snData[this.state.currentIdx].cls = 'animate shown left';
    this.setState({prevIdx: this.state.currentIdx});
    this.setState({currentIdx: this.state.nextIdx});
    this.setState({nextIdx: (this.state.currentIdx === lastSnap ?
      lastSnap: this.state.nextIdx + 1)});
   }.bind(this), 1);
  }

  // on animation complete
  setTimeout(function () {
   this.props.snData[this.state.prevIdx].cls = 'left';
   this.props.snData[this.state.currentIdx].cls = 'shown';
   this.props.snData[this.state.nextIdx].cls = 'next';
   this.setState({animationProgress: false});
  }.bind(this), 1500);
 },
 render: function() {
  return <div>
     <div className="controls">
      <button onClick={this.prev}>&lt;</button>
      <button onClick={this.slideShow}>
       Slide Show {this.state.action}
      </button>
      <button onClick={this.next}>&gt;</button>
     </div>
        {this.props.snData.map(function(item) {
         return <newSlide key={arguments[1]} data={item} />;
        })}
     </div>;
 }
});

ReactDOM.render(
 <snapViewer snData={snapList} />,
    document.getElementById('snapContainer')
);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="icon" href="resources/icons/snaPView.png" type="image/png"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css" type="image/png"/>
 <title>React "snap view" Application</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body class="flex-container">
 <header class="flex-item">
  <h3>snaPView with ReactJS</h3>
 </header>
 <section id="snapContainer" class="flex-item"></section>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="build/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this is the main issue, but the way you try to inject javascript variables into your css is wrong: class="slide-container {this.props.data.cls}" should be class={"slide-container" + this.props.data.cls}. There's another occurrence of this just one line below this one.

Comment: I have changed that code:
<div class={"slide-container" + this.props.data.cls}><div style={"background-image: url(" + this.props.data.path + ");"} class="slide"></div></div>;

Still the issue remains.

Comment: React custom components **must** be capitalized: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259112/why-do-components-in-react-need-to-be-capitalized

Comment: Thanks @Davin. The components are now getting rendered.