# What does ...rest mean in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Looking at this React Router Dom v4 example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow I see that **PrivateRoute** component destructures a rest prop like this

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: props.location }
      }}/>
    )
  )}/>
)
```

I want to be certain that `{ component: Component, ...rest }` means:

> From `props`, get the Component prop and then all other props are given to you, and rename `props` to `rest` so you can avoid naming issues with the props passed to the Route `render` function

Am I right?

Comment: It's a non-standardised yet syntax defined at https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Sorry, I realized my first answer (while hopefully still providing useful/additional context) doesn't answer your question. Let me try again.

You ask:

> I want to be certain that `{ component: Component, ...rest }` means:
>
> From `props`, get the `Component` prop and then all other `props` given to
> you, and rename `props` to `rest` so you can avoid naming issues with the
> `props` passed to the Route `render` function

Your interpretation is not quite correct. Based on your thoughts though, it sounds like you're at least aware of the fact that what is happening here amounts to some sort of [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) (see second answer and comments there for more clarification).

To give an accurate explanation, let's break down the `{ component: Component, ...rest }` expression into two separate operations:

1. **Operation 1:** Find the `component` property defined on `props` (*Note*: lowercase **c**omponent) and assign it to a new location in state we call `Component` (*Note*: capital **C**omponent).
2. **Operation 2:** Then, take all *remaining* properties defined on the `props` object and collect them inside an argument called `rest`.

The important point is that you're NOT renaming `props` to `rest`. (And nor does it have to do with trying to "avoid naming issues with the `props` passed to the Route `render` function".)

```js
rest === props;
// => false
```

You're simply pulling off *the rest* (hence why the argument is named that) of the properties defined on your `props` object into a new argument called `rest`.

---

#### Example Usage

Here's an example. Let's assume we have an object `myObj` defined as follows:

```js
const myObj = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 35,
  sex: 'M',
  dob: new Date(1990, 1, 1)
};
```

For this example, it may help to just think of `props` as having the same structure (*i.e.*, properties and values) as shown in `myObj`. Now, let's write the following assignment.

```js
const { name: Username, ...rest } = myObj
```

The statement above amounts to both the **declaration** and **assignment** of two variables (or, I guess, constants). The statement can be thought out as:

> Take property `name` defined on `myObj` and assign its value to a new
> variable we call `Username`. Then, take whatever other properties were
> defined on `myObj` (*i.e.*, `age`, `sex` and `dob`) and collect them
> into a new object assigned to the variable we name `rest`.

Logging `Username` and `rest` to the `console` would confirm this. We have the following:

```js
console.log(Username);
// => John Doe
```

```js
console.log(rest);
// => { age: 35, sex: 'M', dob: Mon Jan 01 1990 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) }
```

---

#### Side Note

You may wonder:

> Why go through the trouble of pulling off the `component` property
> only to rename it `Component` with a capital letter "C"?

Yeah, it seems pretty trivial. And, while it is a standard React practice, there's a reason all of [Facebook's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) on its framework is written as such. Namely, capitalizing custom components rendered with JSX is less a practice per se than it is a necessity. React, or more properly, [JSX is case-sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259112/why-do-components-in-react-need-to-be-capitalized). Custom components inserted without a capitalized first letter are not rendered to the DOM. This is just how React has defined itself to identify custom components. Thus, had the example not additionally renamed the `component` property that was pulled off of `props` to `Component`, the `<component {...props} />` expression would fail to render properly.

Comment: You should be the one who can re-write the React Docs, your answer shows a passion in teaching that covers every details for beginner while keep everything simple.

Comment: I just create a bounty for you, this is all I can do, enjoy it :)

Answer (score 22):

It allows you to "spread" all your `props` in a single concise expression. For example, let's assume the `props` received by your `PrivateRoute` component looks like

```
// `props` Object:
{
  thing1: 'Something',
  thing2: 'Something else'
}
```

If you wanted to further hand off these items (*i.e.*, `thing1` and `thing2`) down to the nested `<Component />` tag and you weren't familiar with the [**object spread**](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2016/03/es6-features-used-react-development/#rest-spread) syntax, you might write:

```
<Component
  thing1={ props.thing1 }
  thing2={ props.thing2 } />
```

However, the `{ ...props }` syntax obviates such verbosity by allowing you to *spread* your `props` object in the same way one might *spread* an array of values (*e.g.*, `[...vals]`). In other words, the JSX expression below and that above are exactly equivalent.

```
<Component { ...props } />
```

Comment: While related, don't mix JSX's *spread* syntax with *rest properties*.

Comment: *"It allows you to "spread" all your props in a single concise expression."* That's not right. `...rest` in `{ component: Component, ...rest }` *collects* all other properties in the object `rest`. The question is about `...rest`, not `{...props}`

Comment: As Felix notes, there is a distinction to be made between the (non-standard) object _spread_ operator in JSX and the _rest_/_spread_ operator as defined in the ECMAScript 2015 specification. For one thing, attempting to write something like `{ ...myObj }` in a non-React environment (_e.g._, the browser console) will throw a `SyntaxError`. Nevertheless, ES6's _rest_/_spread_ provide a useful conceptual framework in which to think of JSX's object _spread_.

Answer (score 9):

Lets keep it simple: in JavaScript, if a **"key: value"** pairs are the same,
`obj={account:account}` is the same as `obj={account}`. So when passing *props* from parent to child component:

```
const Input = ({name,label,error, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input
        {...rest}
        autoFocus
        name={name}
        id={name}
        className="form-control"
        aria-describedby="emailHelp"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Input;
```

you will be passing *rest of props* as:

```
label={label} placeholder={placeholder} type={type}
```