# Reactjs update grandparent state

Tags: reactjs, session-state

I have just started developing with ReactJs and have been following the serverless-stack.com tutorial. I am ready to extend the application and create a template, with n-child components, but am having trouble managing the users session between grandchild components.

I have App.js which manages the users session. But I have my sign out button in a grandchild component and I can't get it to call the App.js signOut() function.

App.js

```
function App(props) {
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  const onLoad = async () => {
    try {
      await Auth.currentSession();
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e !== "No current user") {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  }

  const signOut = async () => {
    console.log("Signing out.");
    await Auth.signOut();
    userHasAuthenticated(false);
    console.log("signed out.");
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
...
          <Layout
            path='/'
            name='Home'
            {...props}
            onLogout={signOut}
          />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

My Layout component has a bunch of different components such as header, footer, nav etc..

```
function Layout(props) {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
...// header component
          <NavBar
            onLogout={props.onLogout}
            isAuthenticated={props.isAuthenticated}
          />
... //main body and footer components
</div>
);
}
export default Layout;
```

Finally my NavBar grandchild component:

```
function NavBar(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  async function onLoad() {
    console.log("Is authed at navbar? " + props.isAuthenticated);

  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Nav className='ml-auto' navbar>
.. // other NavItems
        <UncontrolledDropdown nav direction='down'>
          <DropdownToggle nav>
            <img
              src={"../../assets/img/usermenu.png"}
              className='img-avatar'
              alt='user menu icon'
            />
          </DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu right>
...
            <DropdownItem onClick={props.onLogout}>
              <i className='fa fa-lock'></i> Logout
            </DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </UncontrolledDropdown>
      </Nav>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

When I load the site and authenticate, the console writes out "Is authed at navbar? True". So I know that the grandchild is correctly getting the `isAuthenticated` state. But when I click the logout button nothing happens and no warnings or errors appear in the console.

Answer (score 0):

At first, in Navbar component, I saw this function

```
async function onLoad() {
    console.log("Is authed at navbar? " + props.isAuthenticated);
}
```

and I tracked to see where did you pass `props.isAuthenticated`. I did find it here

```
<Layout
  path='/'
  name='Home'
  props={props}
  onLogout={signOut}
/>
```

Why do you have a prop named `props`??? If you want to pass all props that passed to parent down to its children (transferring props), please use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). You can see the answer here: [What does it mean ...rest in React JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484302/what-does-it-mean-rest-in-react-jsx)

Comment: It was more for while I was testing if they were getting passed down the line correctly. I have updated the question. But this doesn't have any affect on calling the grandparent function from the grandchild component.

Comment: try it like this.  `onClick={()=>props.onLogout}`

Comment: 1. Can you `console.log(props.onLogout)` to make sure that onLogout is not undefined.   ---
2. Can you change `<DropdownItem onClick={props.onLogout}>` to `<DropdownItem onClick={()=>console.log('onClick works')}>` to verify that callback is really invoked.