# React - HOC that returns a component which uses another HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a HOC "withFirebase" which basically provides my components an interface to communicate with Firebase Services.

Now, I am implementing another HOC "withNotificationsListener" which will receive a component and a path, and then return another component which uses the "withFirebase" HOC.

This is my first time creating a HOC which returns a component that also uses another HOC... My question is basically if this is possible with this code:

```
const withNotificationsListener = (WrappedComponent, notificationsDBPath) =>
  withFirebase((props) => {
    const listenNotifications = () => {};

    useEffect(() => {
      // TODO - Attach db listener subscription
      return () => {
        // TODO - Detach db listener subscription
      };
    }, []);

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  });
```

Following the HOC definition "function that receives a component and returns another component" this make sense to me, because, ultimately, withFirebase returns a component... but I am doubtful since lexically, strictly speaking, I do not return a component directly, but a function.

Would this way of creating this HOC be valid? Or some other way?

Comment: This seems correct to me. You aren't returning a function so much as the result of calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems almost correct since your props can't be Uppercase you would need to destructure them first. When you pass the Component via prop
e.g. component={WrappedComponent}

Than in your WithNotificationListener component you can destructure it.
e.g. const withNotificationsListener = ({component: WrappedComponent, notificationsDBPath}) => ...

That should work.
The link attached goes a little more into depth why you need to destructure the prop.
[Destructure example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484565/11204400)

Comment: I am doubtful about this since according to the documentation a HOC is a function (I think not a functional component). If this were the case, a map would have to be passed to the function as an argument to make the destrcutuing, and not as "props" for a classic Component

Comment: I mean, when using the HOC, I do:

  const NotificationListenerStackButton = withNotificationsListener(
    StackButton,
    notificationsDBPath
  );

<NotificationListenerStackButton {...stackButtonProps} />

  Where StackButton is the original component which will receive the notifications prop from the HOC

Comment: I see, in this case you may not be able to run useEffect inside the HOC if you are strictly using it as a function. UseEffect can only be rendered inside a react component.

Comment: useEffect is executed because it is not inside the function, it is inside a functional component with ES6 syntax.

Comment: anyways I have tried to implement the code and works! Thanks!