# Create a Wrapper ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want create a component which be a DIV with a custom style: background color blue. After that, I want instance it and add text as children. I am trying do it so:

WRAPPER:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Wrapper extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
}

render() {
    const { children, ...props } = this.props;
    return (
        <div style="background-color: blue" {...props}>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

and I am instancing it like so:

INSTANCE:

```
import wrapper from './../../components/wrapper.jsx';

render() {
    return (
        <wrapper>hi world</wrapper>
    );
}
```

But it is not working. How could I do this?. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capitalized "`Wrapper`" in JSX:

```
import Wrapper from './../../components/wrapper.jsx';

render() {
    return (
        <Wrapper>hi world</Wrapper>
    );
}
```

As it described by [@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33259287/2644759):

> From [some react release notes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/10/react-v0.14-rc1.html)
>
> > the JSX tag name convention (lowercase names refer to built-in components, capitalized names refer to custom components).

Comment: WoW! A rookie error...! I did not see it.. Thank you.