# Why does registerServiceWorker.js not have `export default registerServiceWorker;` at the end of it?

Tags: reactjs, components

At the end of `App.js`, we put

```
export default App;
```

to declare `App` as a default export of `app.js`.

Then when we import this file into `index.js`, we simply put

```
//Import default App from file App within this directory.
import App from './App';
```

`registerServiceWorker` is also imported this way.

```
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
```

However, there is no `export default registerServiceWorker` statement contained within `registerServiceWorker.js`.

I have two questions -

**How is this working without there being an `export default registerServiceWorker;` statement inside `registerServiceWorker.js`?**

and also

**Why is registerServiceWorker not capitalized from the start? Is it a [built-in component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33259287/7386637), as stated in this SO answer?**

For reference, here is `registerServiceWorker.js`:

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit https://example'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Because of the "default" keyword. That means its the only export so you can just use the class name.
2. React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.

Remove the "default" keyword, save, and you will get an error. Because it could have multiple exports. The only fix is:

```
 import * as registerServiceWorker from './serviceWorker';

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
 registerServiceWorker();
```

Hope this helps.