# React - Child not rendered correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I can't see the text inside the child component. The child is rendered with size 0x0 and empty.

Is that caused by react router?

this is my code:

---

App.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import home from './pages/home/home';
import repoDetails from "./pages/repoDetails/repoDetails";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
              <Router>
                  <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={home}/>
                      <Route path="/:owner/:repo" component={repoDetails}>
                      </Route>
                  </Switch>
              </Router>
      );}}
```

---

repoDetails.js:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import committersCard from '../../components/committersCard.js'

export default class repoDetails extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <committersCard/>
        </div>
    )}}
```

---

This is the child
committersCard.js:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class committersCard extends Component {

render() {
    return (

        <div style={{height: '150px', width: '200px'}}>
            <h1>TEXT INSIDE THE CHILD COMPONENT</h1>
        </div>
    );}}
```

---

I'm using react router 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do components in react need to be capitalized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259112/why-do-components-in-react-need-to-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb: **Every Component name should start with an uppercase**

Answer (score 1):

Your custom element must start with an upper-case letter and your class name is also supposed to start with an upper-case

---

`repoDetails.js:`

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CommittersCard from '../../components/committersCard.js'

export default class RepoDetails extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <CommittersCard />
        </div>
    )}}
```

---

`committersCard.js`

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class CommittersCard extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{height: '150px', width: '200px'}}>
            <h1>TEXT INSIDE THE CHILD COMPONENT</h1>
        </div>
    );}}*
```

---

`App.js`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import home from './pages/home/home';
import RepoDetails from "./pages/repoDetails/repoDetails";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
              <Router>
                  <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={home}/>
                      <Route path="/:owner/:repo" component={RepoDetails} /> //fixed
                      </Route>
                  </Switch>
              </Router>
      );}}
```

---

The reason is:

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div'
>   or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
>   component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
>   capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

According to [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use custom components, they MUST start with a capital letter.

From the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

> Note: Always start component names with a capital letter.
>
> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.
>   For example,  represents an HTML div tag, but 
>   represents a component and requires Welcome to be in scope.
>
> You can read more about the reasoning behind this convention [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

So, replace the names of your components with:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CommittersCard from '../../components/CommittersCard.js'

export default class RepoDetails extends Component {

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <CommittersCard/>
        </div>
    )}}
```

and

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class CommittersCard extends Component {

render() {
    return (

        <div style={{height: '150px', width: '200px'}}>
            <h1>TEXT INSIDE THE CHILD COMPONENT</h1>
        </div>
    );}}
```

Comment: @robo you are very welcome. I suggest always following the official docs, it will save you lots of time and will help you keep to React standards to avoid simple issues like this.