# is there any way to use lowercase letter for a component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to make some component , I'm new in React and I tried with some basics like creating simple component that stored `<h1></h1>` tag with `Hello World` in it . I noticed that when I'm turning `Myfunc`'s first letter to lowercase "m" it is rendering nothing but empty page  although I'm changing it trough the `something.js` too , I searched in the web and it seems that there's something like rule here , anyway...
is there anyway to use component with lowercase ? I'm forgetting that rule many time

```
import React from "react";
import Myfunc from "./something.js";
function App(){
    return(
       <div>
         <Myfunc/>
       </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: [Have at it.](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33259112/why-do-components-in-react-need-to-be-capitalized?

Comment: @misha130 yes , but I'm forgetting to capitalize many time , what can I do ?

Comment: @JSXStarter that habit will go with time. It's better to adopt the standards which majority follows.

Comment: @AvinashThakur yes I think it is the only way

Comment: There is also an exception where if the component has a dot in the name like obj.component then its rendered as a react component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some part of the docs...maybe from here you can get a better idea.

When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have React components with lowercase name, but you can't use them in JSX.

If you strictly don't want to capitalize the first letter, or don't want to reassign it to a capitalized variable ( `ReactComp = reactComp` ), then you can follow this ugly looking approach.

```js
const myFunc = (props) => {
  const { name, children } = props;
  return <div>
    <h1> {name} </h1>
    <h3> a lower case component </h3>
    {children}
  </div>
}

const App = props => {
  return (
    React.createElement(
      myFunc,
      {
        name: 'My Func',
        // other props
      },
      <h6>This is a child component</h6>,
      <h6>This is another child component</h6>
    )
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Jeez ! looks complex !

Comment: actually I want to use capitalize letter but I'm forgetting it many time

Comment: It sure it complex and ugly, but it is something what your JSX code will ultimately be converted to.
I'm sure this will keep you away from using lower-case names.